# How would i slightly lower my image in my text?

Tags: html, css

I have an image inserted in my table i created when you press a button, it displays the table, but i want the image in my text on the actual website to be slightly lower, how can i do that?

code:

```
     <div id="demo" style="display:none"><font color="white"><b>Fav Color:</b> Orange/Purple<br><b>Hobbies:</b> Coding, Video games, Hanging out with friends, Drifting<br><b>Fav Song:</b> Homocide - Logic (ft. Eminem)<br><b>Fav Animal:</b> Cat<br><b>Fav Food:</b> Pulled Pork Sandwich<br><b>My Fav Game:</b> Fortnite <img src="https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/FortniteLogo.png" width="32px" height="32px"></font></div>
```

[image]

i would like the F logo to be slightly lower and more in line with the word Fortnite if you know what i mean

Comment: @AlonEitan He could be learning how to code, no need to diss him on the way he goes about it. Sure there are alternatives to what he may be writing, but if that's how he's going about it, leave him to it or give him some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should no longer use the `<font>` tag, as it is no longer part in HTML5, even though current browser may support it.

You should use paragraphs `<p>` instead and declare your font styles in the styles property. Look here for an example. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

If you change your code to the paragraphs it could look something like this:

```
<div id="demo" style="text-align: center; color: white;">
    <p>Fav Color:</p>
    <p>Hobbies:</p>
    <p>Fav Song:</p>
    <p>Fav Animal:</p>
    <p>Fav Food:</p>
    <p>My Fav Game: Fortnite <img style="position: relative; top: 5px;" src="https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/FortniteLogo.png" width="32px" height="32px"></p>
</div>
```

The specific code you are looking for to bring the image down a bit:

`<img style="position: relative; top: 5px;" ... />`

If you want to center it according to the text, then you could do the following:
`<img style="position: relative; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)" ... />`

`top: 50%` will let the image start at the vertical-center from your text. While `transform: translateY(-50%)`will bring it back upwards by half the image height.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest applying `vertical-align: middle;` to the image.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <font color="white">
    <b>Fav Color:</b> Orange/Purple<br>
    <b>Hobbies:</b> Coding, Video games, Hanging out with friends, Drifting<br>
    <b>Fav Song:</b> Homocide - Logic (ft. Eminem)<br>
    <b>Fav Animal:</b> Cat<br>
    <b>Fav Food:</b> Pulled Pork Sandwich<br>
    <b>My Fav Game:</b> Fortnite
    <img src="https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/FortniteLogo.png" width="32px" height="32px" style='vertical-align: middle;'>
  </font>
</div>
```

Also some general points that are unrelated to your problem, but would improve the code:

- Generally the `font` and `b` tags are avoided in modern HTML, using a `p` tag with `span`s for bold text would be better.
- Applying styles inline is best avoided, ideally you would give your elements classes and use a style sheet to apply styles

Answer (score 1):

Add a margin at the top.

`margin-top: 10px;`

Answer (score 0):

Negative margin will lower it.
Give it

```
margin-bottom: -8px;
```

or so.

Answer (score 0):

I've redone a bit of your code to make it a bit more readable. I eliminated the **br** tags and inserted **p** tags. The way I aligned your image was by inserting a flex-container **div** around the Fortnite text and the Fortnite image. Then, by using inline-styles (not recommended, it is much better to make a CSS stylesheet and connect it to your HTML file) I applied display to 'flex', and align items to 'center'. This basically aligns everything within the **div** vertically.

```
<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <p><b>Fav Color:</b> Orange/Purple</p>
    <p><b>Hobbies:</b> Coding, Video games, Hanging out with friends, Drifting</p>
    <p><b>Fav Song:</b> Homocide - Logic (ft. Eminem)</p>
    <p><b>Fav Animal:</b> Cat</p>
    <p><b>Fav Food:</b> Pulled Pork Sandwich</p>
    <div class="flex-container" style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
      <p><b>My Fav Game:</b> Fortnite</p>
      <img src="https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/FortniteLogo.png" width="32px" height="32px" style="padding-left: 10px">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```